# Content divider using HTML or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How do I add content divider every time the next question pops up. It doesn't matter what kind of divider as long as it has a small show above it or below it. I'm open to javascript and HTML.

Example:

q1 q2 q3 q4 (when q1 is chosen, another form pops up along with a content divider)

---

q5 q6 q7 q8 (When q6 is chosen, another form pops up with another divider and so)

Here's the jsfiddle: (click buttons to see form in action): http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/ffKKN/6/

Here's the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.radio div').on('click', function () {
var $this = $(this),
    $parent = $this.parent(),
    value = $this.attr('value');

$parent.children().removeClass('active');
$this.addClass('active');
$parent.attr('value', value);

//get all selected radios
var q1 = $('div[name="q1"].active');
var q2 = $('div[name="q2"].active');
var q3 = $('div[name="q3"].active');
var q4 = $('div[name="q4"].active');

//make sure the user has selected all 3
if (q1.length !== 0 && q2.length !== 0 && q3.length !== 0 && q4.length !== 0) {
    //now we know we have 3 radios, so get their values
    q1 = q1.attr('value');
    q2 = q2.attr('value');
    q3 = q3.attr('value');
    q4 = q4.attr('value');

    // activate button
    $('#next_button').removeAttr('disabled');

    //now check the values to display a different link for the desired  
configuration
    if (q1 == "AT&T" && q2 == "8GB" && q3 == "Black" && q4 == "Black") {
        $('#next_button').val('att 8gb black').click(function () {
            window.location.href = 'http://google.com/'
        });
    } else if (q1 == "AT&T" && q2 == "16GB" && q3 == "White" && q4 == "Black") {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button 
value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://bing.com/';\">another  
option</input>";
    } else if (q1 == "AT&T" && q2 == "16GB" && q3 == "Black" && q4 == "Black") {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button 
value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://gmail.com/';\">oops</input>";
    } else if (q1 == "AT&T" && q2 == "8GB" && q3 == "White" && q4 == "Black") {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button 
value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://hotmail.com/';\">can't</input>";
    } else if (q1 == "Unlocked" && q2 == "8GB" && q3 == "White" && q4 == "Black") {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button 
value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://wepriceit.webs.com/';\">red</input>";
    } else if (q1 == "Unlocked" && q2 == "8GB" && q3 == "Black" && q4 == "Black") {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button  
value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://webs.com/';\">orange</input>";
    } else if (q1 == "Unlocked" && q2 == "16GB" && q3 == "White" && q4 == "Black")     
{
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button  
value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://gazelle.com/';\">green</input>";
    } else if (q1 == "Unlocked" && q2 == "16GB" && q3 == "Black" && q4 == "Black")  
{
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button  
value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='http://glyde.com/';\">blue</input>";
    } else if (q1 == "AT&T") {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML = "<input type=button 
value=Next onclick=\"iphone4';\">blue</input>";
    }
}

});

var questions = $(".question");
var showQuestions = function (index) {
for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    if (i < index) {
        questions.eq(i).css("display", "block");

    } else {
        questions.eq(i).css("display", "none");
    }
}

if (index > 1) {
    // only scroll to the questions after the first one is clicked
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop : $(questions.eq(index - 1)).offset().top
    },'slow');
}
}

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
(function (index) {
    questions.eq(index).find("div[type='radio']").on("click", function () {
        showQuestions(index + 2);
    })
})(i);
}
showQuestions(1);

}); //]]>
```

Comment: Fyi, a `<div>` has neither `name` or `value` attributes.

Comment: So a div is basically pointless? @ThiefMaster

Comment: Why would a `div` be pointless just because it doesn't have a `name` or `value` attribute?  Those attributes only make sense on input elements anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ffKKN/7/

This [selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) matches "question immediately preceded by a question":

```
.question + .question {
    border-top: 1px solid silver;
}
```

To make this work, I had to remove the `<br style="clear:both"/>` elements (which aren't a good idea anyway). These elements were separating your `.question` elements.

You may have to tweak spacing to make it look the way you want (perhaps like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ffKKN/9/), which adds `margin-bottom:2em` to each question).

Another version, tweaked to include spacing and to display a consistently wide divider: http://jsfiddle.net/ffKKN/10/

Comment: This is elegant, one learns new things every day on stackoverflow =)

Comment: This is really cool but how do I set a width to this so it stays the same throughout the whole form?

Comment: It's based on the width of the element (since it is just a border), so you would need all the questions to have the same outer size (they could have different content still).

Comment: Added another version: http://jsfiddle.net/ffKKN/10/. You can set an explicit width on the .question divs if you want too (if you don't want it to span the whole page). Here's one with a fixed width on the questions: http://jsfiddle.net/ffKKN/11/

Answer (score 0):

what about something simple like:

```
.question {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

let me know if I didn't understand your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could put a HR tag between the questions, here's how to alter the showQuestions function to add that.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        if (i < index) {
            questions.eq(i).css("display", "block"); 
            if (i > 0) {
                questions.eq(i).before('<hr>'); 
            }
        } else {
            questions.eq(i).css("display", "none");
        }
    }
```

Another silly option:

```
.question + .question::before {
    content: "───────────────────────";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you altered the first  tag to include this:

```
    <h4 class="top">What is your current carrier?</h4>
```

then added this at the top of your jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    <~~ immediately below this line
    $("h4:not(.top)").append("<hr />");
```

it would also provide to your inquiry